# How to query grove sensors status?

Tags: sensors

I have some Seeedstudio Grove sensors I'd like to access from linux.  Eventually, I need to access them from a C++ application, but figuring out how to access them using a standard binary.

The grove sensors I'm talking about are any of the modules from here:  http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_System#Grove_Modules

I expected them to show up somewhere like `/sys/devices/platform/`, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Anyone know how these sensors show up under linux?

Comment: Normally, you only need to `cat /dev/sensors`, sensors being whatever path your module creates for them. Also, they seems to provide python libraries http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_Digital_Light_Sensor#With_Raspberry_Pi